# CSS3 Hover Effect Re-position problems

Tags: html, css, web, hover, position

I'm trying to get this CSS effect into the middle of all of these boxes, and add a fade just like this site demo's http://dinolatoga.com/demo/webkit-image-hover-effects/ (the bottom right effect) But I don't know how to re-size the effect to fit into these boxes here's happens when I run my code http://jsfiddle.net/TWebQ/

and here's my code:

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<div>

    <img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v604/Ema/header-winter-castle-900x200.jpg" class="banner">
    </>



</div>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">



.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:450px;
    margin:0px auto;

}
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:1px;


}

.spacing{
    margin-right:20px;
}

.banner{
 margin:0 auto;
display:block;
border:4px solid black;
padding:5px;
}

#one{
 position:relative;
 }
 #one img{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:0;
 }
 #one .detailsone{
 opacity: .9;
 position:absolute;
 top:100;
 left:150;
 z-index:999;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
 padding-right:200px;
 }
 #one:hover .detailsone{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
 padding-right:100px;

 }  
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="box spacing" id="one";><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%">

    </a>
    <div class="detailsone"> 
    <h1 style="color:black"> <u> Enter </u> </h1> 

    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="box spacing"id="two";><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"  width="100%">

        </a>
    <div class="detailstwo"> 
    <h1 style="color:black"> <u> Enter </u> </h1> 

    </div>
        </div>

            <div class="box spacing"id="three";><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"  width="100%">

            </a>
        <div class="detailsthree"> 
    <h1 style="color:black"> <u> Enter </u> </h1> 

    </div>
            </div>
                <div class="box spacing"id="four";><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"  width="100%" >

                </a>
                <div class="detailsfour"> 
<h1 style="color:black"> <u> Enter </u> </h1> 

</div>


</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, If I find a answer I'll update this thread, Thank you for reading.

Comment: You have a div _before_ the body element, strange semicolons all over the place, an empty closing tag and width as an attrribute! You should clean up your markup before trying to debug anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you do have to cleanup your HTML to something like this:

```
<body>
<div>
    <img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v604/Ema/header-winter-castle-900x200.jpg" class="banner"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing" id="one">
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"/></a>
        <div class="detailsone">
            <h1>Enter</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box spacing" id="two">
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"/></a>
        <div class="detailstwo">
            <h1>Enter</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box spacing" id="three">
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"/></a>
        <div class="detailsthree">
            <h1>Enter</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box spacing" id="four">
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"/></a>
        <div class="detailsfour">
            <h1>Enter</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Also, you might want to consider if you do want to use multiple H1 tags without a good reason.
read more about this in the article [on-page-seo-multiple-h1-elements](http://website-in-a-weekend.net/building-traffic/on-page-seo-multiple-h1-elements/) on website-in-a-weekend.net/

And if your css is like this it will work:

```
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:1px;
}

.spacing{
    margin-right:20px;
}
.banner{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border:4px solid black;
    padding:5px;
}
#one{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
#one img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
.box h1{
    color:black;
}
#one .detailsone{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    opacity: .9;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
#one:hover .detailsone{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
```

See it in action on this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwvanveelen/KW5Uh/